# Как сгруппировать одномерный массив слов по одинаковым символам в элементе?

Tags: php

Необходимо написать функцию, которая принимает на вход массив со списком слов и возвращает сгруппированные слова. К одной группе относятся слова, которые могут быть получены одно из другого с помощью произвольной перестановки букв.

Например:
array('rfv', 'vfr', 'abc', 'bac', 'dbatre', 'qwer', 'cba', 'terbda')

Должно получиться:
array(
array('rfv', 'vfr'),
array('abc', 'bac', 'cba'),
array('dbatre', 'terbda'),
array('qwer'),
)

Здесь rfv получается из vfr с помощью перестановки v и r, а из слов abc, bac и cba формируется общая группа, потому что любое из этих слов превращается в соседнее путём одной или нескольких перестановок букв. Т.е. нужно проверить каждый элемент на одинаковые символы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sortString($str){
    // разбиваем строку на массив букв
    $letters = str_split(strtolower($str));
    // сортируем массив букв 
    sort($letters);
    // соединяем массив букв в слово и возвращаем его
    return implode($letters);
}

//входные данные
$array = array('rfv', 'vfr', 'abc', 'bac', 'dbatre', 'qwer', 'cba', 'terbda');

// будем проходиться по массиву используся функцию array_reduce(),
// с callback-функцией, которая возвращает заново сформированный массив
$grouppedArray = array_reduce($array, function($accumulator, $item) {
    // пользуемся выше созданной функцией которая сортируем по алфавиту слово
    $itemSorted = sortString($item);
    // записываем в возвращаемый массив новое значение 
    // с ключом вида отсортированного ранее слова,
    // или добавляем его, если существует такой массив
    $accumulator[$itemSorted][] = $item;
    // возвращаем общий массив для следующей итерации
    return $accumulator;
});
```

Теперь переменная `$grouppedArray` будет содержать массив вида

```
array(4) {
  ["frv"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "rfv"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "vfr"
  }
  ["abc"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "abc"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "bac"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "cba"
  }
  ["abdert"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "dbatre"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "terbda"
  }
  ["eqrw"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "qwer"
  }
}
```

Если далее нужно поменять ключи массив на цифровые - можно воспользоваться [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php)

```
array_values($grouppedArray);
```